# google smart home actions implement offline response issue

Tags: google-smart-home

I implement google smart home actions for plug device,
I can control on/off plug with no problems, but about implement
response offline status for Execute and Query, it seems google assistant never get status, it always said "OK, turn on/off plug", My response JSON log from cloud function log as below:

Execute:

```
   {
    "requestId": "847886417406301663",
    "payload": {
      "commands": {
        "ids": [
          "T90197200015"
        ],
        "status": "ERROR",
        "errorCode": "deviceOffline",
        "online": false
      }
    }
  }
```

Query:

```
   {
    "requestId": "11887439270473779795",
    "payload": {
      "devices": {
        "T90197200015": {
          "errorCode": "deviceOffline",
          "status": "ERROR",
          "online": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Is the format correct, why google assistant didn't get offline status?

BR,
Jack

Answer (score 0):

Yes that format is correct. The device generally may be `offline`, sending the `status: "ERROR"` and `errorCode` are more contextually applied to the specific request and response.